# Toggle between element list and jogging elements with arrow keys?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

i worry that my xcode vocabulary is insufficient here -

in Interface Builder,
i frequently would like to use the precise element-selection of the hierarchical element list, and then switch to jogging the position/size of the elements with the arrow keys.

the only way i know to do this is to carefully click on one of the drag-boxes revealed around an element when it's selected, which shifts keyboard focus from the element list into the visual layout.  but this is difficult and error-prone because it's easy to accidentally move the element a bit, or the drag-box may be underneath another element, or you may have multiple elements selected, etc, so a hotkey of some sort would be ideal.

apologies for not having the right names for all the things here.
even the names would probably help me search.

Comment: thanks @thinkingstiff for the edits - i didn't realize signing off w/ a 'tia' was not the stackoverflow way, but i can see how it makes sense. cheers, ooo.

Comment: Yeah, any sort of taglines or signoffs are discouraged: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A: obvious but i missed it - double-click the element in the hierarchy.  it would be nice if there were a keyboard command to do this, but i'll settle for the double-click.